# Как получить более одного вида данных через ajax

Tags: ajax, php, json, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Реализую возможность уведомлений в системе, но не пойму как получить от ajax запроса данные и занести их в разные переменные.

1) Есть данные уведомлений

2) Данные о количестве уведомлений

После получения они должны быть расставлены по разным контейнерам.

код js:

```
function notification(){

        $.ajax({

            url: "ajax_notification.php",

            cache: false,

            success: function(response){ 
                if (response !== '') {

                    $(".notification-content").html(response);
                    soundClick();

                } else {
                    $(".notification-content").html('<div class="none-notification">У вас нет новых оповещений! </div>');
                }
                if (count_lids !== '0') {

                    $(".notification-icon").html('<div class="notification-count">'+ +'</div>');

                }
            }

        });

    }
```

Код php

```
        $response = '';
    $count_lids = '';
    $request  = mysql_query("SELECT `tel`, `name`, `id`, `email`  FROM `mes` WHERE status_view = '1' and id_cabinet = '$myrow_cabinet[id]' LIMIT 0, 10");
    $count_lids = mysql_num_rows($request);
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($request)){
        $search_id = iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8",$data['id']);
        $search_name = iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8",$data['name']);
        $search_email = iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8",$data['email']);
        $search_phone = iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8",$data['tel']);
        $response .= '<a href=details-'.$data['id'].' ><div class=search_name>'.$search_name.'</div></a><br>';

    }

    echo json_encode($response);
    echo json_encode($count_lids);
```

Работает, но почему-то данные приходят так

http://joxi.ru/GrqM86bfN1b3rz

походу что-то я забыл или сделал неправильно =/ помогите...

Comment: Нету не типа данных, не типа запроса. Как вы вообще сообразили такой `ajax` запрос.

Answer (score 1):

Я себе представляю все немного иначе.

Выход из php:

```
exit(json_encode(array(
    'notif' => $response,
    'count' => $count_lids
)));
```

Обработка в js:

```
function notification(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax_notification.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            if (response.notif !== '') {
                $(".notification-content").html(response.notif);
                soundClick();
            } else {
                $(".notification-content").html('<div class="none-notification">У вас нет новых оповещений! </div>');
            }
            if (response.count !== '0') {
                $(".notification-icon").html('<div class="notification-count">'+ response.count +'</div>');
            }
        }
    });
}
```